# how to log(slf4j) once a hour to reduce log frequesncy

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I have a very frequently used java class and I only want to log a statement every hour, not all the time. this is to stop unwanted log frequency.
I can have a timer initialized and only log once the timer reached 60 minutes, Is there any other elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any rate limiting filter that comes off the shelf with logback. It seems one has to implement one's own filter. A good template can be found [here](https://github.com/abusix/rate-limiting-logback-filter).

log4j allows specifying filters that can limit the rate of logging as per [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html).
You can use a BurstFilter in your appender and specify how many events per second you want (it's a float, so you can pass a value < 1):

```xml
<BurstFilter level="INFO" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
```

As you don't want this to be applied globally, you can create a separate appender specially for this verbose Java class.